# Update Azure tags of resources

Tags: azure, tags, azure-powershell

I am pretty new to powershell and please bear with me. I am building a script wherein I need to replace one of the key value pairs of a Tag of any resources in a certain subscription. It can be the "***Name***" or "***Value***"  of a Tag.

I got a script that will find and old Tag key and replace it with a new Tag key. It checks all resources and locate the old tag and replace it with a new tag successfully. Now, my dilemma is it only do the job for the "***Name***" part of Tag but not with the "***Value***" of the tag. Can anyone help me on how to do the "***Value***" part of the Tag, please.

Over all, the code will search for a tag from *$oldKey* across all the resources and replace it with *$newKey*. It does create a report of what resources it made changes and put it to a csv file.

```
#Define old Tag key $oldkey and new Tag key $newKey
$oldKey = "camp"
$newKey = "Camp3"

#Find ResourceGroups with oldKey, backup findings to CSV, migrate existing oldKey value to newKey merging with existing tags, then delete oldKey.
$rgsOldKeyBackup = Get-AzResourceGroup | Where-Object {$_.Tags.Keys -match $oldKey}
$rgsOldKeyBackup.count
if ($rgsOldKeyBackup) {
    Get-AzResourceGroup | Where-Object {$_.Tags.Keys -match $oldKey} | Out-File "C:\temp\AzRGs-Tag-Backup-$oldkey.csv"
    $rgs = Get-AzResourceGroup | Where-Object {$_.Tags.Keys -match $oldKey}
    $rgs | ForEach-Object {
        $rgOldKeyValue = $_.Tags.$oldKey
        $rgNewTag = @{$newKey=$rgOldKeyValue}
        $rgOldTag = @{$oldKey=$rgOldKeyValue}
        $resourceID = $_.ResourceId
        Update-AzTag -ResourceId $resourceID -Tag $rgNewTag -Operation Merge
        $Check = Get-AzResourceGroup -Id $resourceID | Where-Object {$_.Tags.Keys -match $newKey}
        if ($Check) {
            Update-AzTag -ResourceId $resourceID -Tag $rgOldTag -Operation Delete
        }
    }   
}

#Find Resources with oldKey, backup findings to CSV, migrate existing oldKey value to newKey merging with existing tags, then delete oldKey.
$resourcesOldKeyBackup = Get-AzResource | Where-Object {$_.Tags.Keys -match $oldKey}
$resourcesOldKeyBackup.count
if ($resourcesOldKeyBackup) {
    Get-AzResource | Where-Object {$_.Tags.Keys -match $oldKey} | Out-File "C:\temp\AzResources-Tag-Backup-$oldkey.csv"
    $resources = Get-AzResource | Where-Object {$_.Tags.Keys -match $oldKey}
    $resources | ForEach-Object {
        $resourcesOldKeyValue = $_.Tags.$oldKey
        $resourcesNewTag = @{$newKey=$resourcesOldKeyValue}
        $resourcesOldTag = @{$oldKey=$resourcesOldKeyValue}
        $resourceID = $_.ResourceId
        Update-AzTag -ResourceId $resourceID -Tag $resourcesNewTag -Operation Merge
        $Check = Get-AzResource -ResourceId $resourceID | Where-Object {$_.Tags.Keys -match $newKey}
        if ($Check) {
            Update-AzTag -ResourceId $resourceID -Tag $resourcesOldTag -Operation Delete
        }
    }
}
```

Also, I would appreciate if you can help as well to make it more interactive and will ask to input an old key I am looking for and what will be the replacement instead of hardcoding the values in the script itself.

Comment: sorry, i dont think i understand what are you asking for. if this does what you ask for (replaces tag name with a new one and preserves the value) what else do you want ?

Comment: @4c74356b41, what I am trying to achieve is the code should be able to search between the key value pairs, which is "Name : Value". The current code only search for the "Name" and disregard the "Value" part. What I am trying to achieve is to also search on either the "Name" or "Value" and replace it as well.

Comment: so if key == x, replace key with newX and if value == y, replace value with newY?

Comment: @ 4c74356b41, Apologies for the late revert as I got hold on something. Yes, the logic is right.

Comment: so whats the point exactly? i mean if you replace something with identical value - nothing changes?

Comment: Sorry for the confution. Let's say I want to change a Tag's Name with a NewName, I will search for resources with the Tag Name and replace it with NewName. If I want to change a Tag's Value with a NewValue, I will search for resources with the Tag Value and replace it with NewValue. It is not necessary that I want to change both key value pair of a tag. Sometimes, it is jut the Name, and sometimes just the Value. If you got what I mean. I am thinking that the end result of this is 2 separate scripts, which I already have the 1st one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I Tried to reproduce the same in my environment to replace the Azure Tags using Powershell:**

**PowerShell Script:**

```
   connect-azaccount
   $oldTagKey = "OldTagKey"
   $oldTagValue = "OldTagValue"
   $replacedTags= @{"NewTagKey"="NewTagValue"}
    #$resourcelist= Get-AzResource
    $resources = Get-AzResourceGroup | Where-Object {$_.Tags.Keys -match "OldTagKey"}
    foreach($item in $resources){
   # Get the current tags for the resource
        $tags = $item.Tags
        if ($tags.ContainsKey($oldTagKey)) {
  # Update the tag with the new tag key and value
        $tags[$newTagKey] = $newTagValue
        # Remove the old tag
        $tags.Remove($oldTagKey)
        Update-Aztag -ResourceId $item.ResourceId -Tag $replacedTags -Operation Replace  
        }
}
```

**Azure Tag** **Name** and **Value** both are updated with new values.

[image]

Once ran the above commands **Tags** are updated in **Resource Group**.

[image]

Refer [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/update-aztag?view=azps-9.4.0) more about **Azure Tags** using **Powershell**.

Comment: Hi @Venkat, Thank you for the updated code. Appreciate it. I really does find the value and replace it however, what if I only need to change the "Name" part and not the "Value" part and vice versa?

Comment: Try this code for changing only Tag Value: 

$tagKey = "NewTagKey"
$oldTagValue = "OldTagValue"
$newTagValue = "NewTagValue"
$resources = Get-AzResourceGroup | Where-Object {$_.Tags.Keys -match "NewTagKey"}
foreach($item in $resources){
 
   $tags = $item.Tags
   if ($tags[$tagKey] -eq $oldTagValue) {
    
      $tags[$tagKey] = $newTagValue
      Update-AzTag -ResourceId $item.ResourceId -Tag $tags -Operation Replace
   }
}

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. The script will search for a Tag ($tagKey) that will match on all resource group. all matches will replace the $oldTagValue with $newTagValue?

Comment: Yes, The script will search all resource groups.

Answer (score 0):

to search for resource groups with tag name or value equals to `xxx`:

```
$searchPattern = 'xxx'
$resourceGroups = Search-AzGraph "ResourceContainers | where tags contains '$searchPattern' and type =~ 'microsoft.resources/subscriptions/resourcegroups'"
```

and then you just have to iterate over the result pretty much the same way you do. main advantage over your code - this scans all available subscriptions and does filtering on Azure side, so a lot quicker.